# Dynamically change SQL statement with IIF

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, iif

Very simple question but kept me stuck for hours now.

I want to change the 'Gender' field to like this
If Gender is 0, then 1
If Gender is 1, then 2

This is my code:

```
Private Sub Run_Click()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim queryDef As DAO.queryDef
    Dim sql As String
    Dim fields As Variant

    Set db = CurrentDb
    sql = ""

    fields = Array("Name", "Gender", "Age")

    For Each queryDef In db.QueryDefs
        If queryDef.Name = "Q_List" Then
            db.QueryDefs.Delete "Q_List"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    sql = sql & "SELECT "
    For Each field In fields
        If field = "Gender" Then
            sql = sql & IIf([Gender] = 0, 1, 2) & " AS Gender, "
        Else
            sql = sql & "[" & field & "]" & ", "
        End If
    Next
    sql = Left(sql, Len(sql) - 2)
    sql = sql & " FROM T_Customer"
    Set queryDef = db.CreateQueryDef("Q_List", sql)

    DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "Q_List", "C:\customerdata\data.txt", True, , 65001

    MsgBox "Done!"

End Sub
```

The problem is, the IIF does not apply to all the rows of data but it literally compare if Gender which is a string equals to 0 integer, and all my Gender rows becomes 2...
Sql generated is as follow:

```
SELECT T_Customer.[Name], 2 AS Gender, T_Customer.[Age] FROM T_Customer
```

Need Help Please

> **SOLVED!!!**

By writing IIF in sql statement IN STRING, and to use the same field name, write as so:
    IIf([tablemame].[Gender] = 0, 1, 2) & " AS Gender, "

Comment: Why is `Gender` a string if it only contains integers?

Comment: I think vba tries to compare literally like this "Gender" = 0, which is always false, and thus my Gender field all returns 2, does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have omitted two quotation marks. The line after if in object loop should be:

```
sql = sql & " IIf([Gender] = 0, 1, 2) " & " AS Gender, "
```

now sql variable is

```
SELECT [Name],  IIf([Gender] = 0, 1, 2)  AS Gender, [Age] FROM T_Customer
```

Comment: I tried this, and I got an error saying 'Circular reference caused by alias 'Gender' in query definition's SELECT list. (Error 3103)'

Comment: change alias to Gen or something.

Comment: Oh my god, so simple. This worked. One advice I can give to myself and all the non-native speaker, read the error message, dont discard it...It seems like by making the IIF a string, VBA register it into its sql conditional object.